# Improving the speed of a Loop's performance?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, do-loops

I currently have to workbooks, **Test 1** (the name of the first workbook where the code is written) and **Test 2** (where values are pasted into from **Test 1**). My current code takes the values from **Rows K1-K10 (Column 11, Rows 1-10)** from the **Test 1** workbook and pastes them into **Columns F2-P2 (Row 2, Columns 6-16)** of the **Test 2** workbook (**THE FIRST CODE IS WORKING**).

I am trying to make this **code run faster** as when I use it for my other applications, I feel as if the loop makes it laggy and sluggish. I am trying to **replace** the ***Do (While) Loop*** with a ***Double (For) Loop statement***. Please let me know if you have a suggestion as my ***Double (For) Loop*** is not pasting any values into the **Test 2** workbook (Also how do I measure the time it takes for each function to run).

Here are both codes and screenshots as well for visual aid:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim y As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
i = 6
j = 1

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\FILEPATH\Databases\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf")

    With y



        Do While j <= 11
            If (Cells(j, 11).Value <> "") Then

                .Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"
                .Sheets("Mytest2").Cells(2, i).Value = Sheet1.Cells(j, 11).Value

            End If

        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1

        Loop



        .Password = "Swarf"
        .Save
        .Close False

    End With


End Sub
```

Here is my attempted code at a Double (for) Loop:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim y As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\FILEPATH\Databases\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf")

    With y

        For i = 6 To 16
          For j = 1 To 10


            If (Cells(i, 11).Value <> "") Then

                .Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"
                .Sheets("Mytest2").Cells(2, i).Value = Sheet1.Cells(j, 11).Value

            End If

          Next j
        Next i

        .Password = "Swarf"
        .Save
        .Close False

    End With


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You only need to unprotect the sheet once. do it outside the loop. If your code works and you just want to improve it, then this question may be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you just transposing values? If so, there's no need for any loop at all.

Comment: In the first case (while), in each loop, both i and j  are incremented once, so there will be 11 runs. in the second case (for), you have two loops one inside the other, so you will have 11 (j=1->11) x 11 (i=6->16) runs. They don't do the same thing, and I doubt the second one can be faster.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I appreciate the suggestion but my second code is not working so that's why I posted it here. and would I just put "  .Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"  " just above the with statement or above Do While?

Comment: Range `K1-K10` contains 10 cells and you are pasting them into range `F2-P2`, which is 11 cells...Anyways, why don't you just copy the 10/11 values and then paste them transposed into cell `F2`?

Comment: If you want it faster, don't copy data cell by cell, copy them by bloc.

Comment: @Handreen `.Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"` the `.` at the beginning means it is being referenced by a `With` statement, so it needs to go just after the `With` for example.

Comment: @BigBen Yes essentially I am transposing values now that I think about it, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I fully agree with @BigBen here, transposing doesn't have to be done with a loop. If you do insist doing it this way, you should put `application.screenupdating = false` at the start and `application.screenupdating = true` at the end of your code. This will stop displaying everything you do on screen until it is done, which will increase performance.

Comment: @Handreen you can `.Copy` and then `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True` and that would do it.

Comment: [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) then [PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) with the transpose argument? Or Copy to an array, [Transpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) the array, and then copy back?

Comment: Hint: `destination.Range("F2:O2") = Application.Transpose(source.Range("K1:K10"))`, given destination and source are set to the right (unprotected) worksheets.

Comment: Thank you all for the excellent answers

Comment: @Plutian Do I just put the application.screenupdating=false right after my Private Sub and the application.screenupdating=true right before my End sub? and I am having a hard time writing the function to transpose for some reason

Comment: @VincentG how would I incorporate that into my code and remove the loop statement? would you mind showing me, thanks in advance

Comment: Anywhere before your first operation will do. Common practise is to put it just after your `Dim` statements, and the `True` one just before `End Sub`

Comment: @Damian I currently have ~~~Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim y As Workbook

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\schaeffler.com\stratford\DATA\NEA-FBA-P\Projects\SetupSheets\Databases\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf")
    With y
                Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"
                .Sheet1.Range("K1:K10").Copy
                .Sheets("Mytest2").Range("F2-P2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        Password = "Swarf"
        .Save
        .Close False
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: @Plutian thank you for clarifying what the common practice is, could you please let me know what the code is supposed to look like by just simply transposing in my case?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that slow. Remove some dots. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596432/pointers-needed-for-speeding-up-nested-loop-macro-in-vba/29597193#29597193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To much code to write in a comment, but here you go:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\FILEPATH\Databases\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf").Sheets("MyTest2")
        .Unprotect "Swarf"
        .Range("F2:O2") = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("K1:K10"))
        .Protect "Swarf"
        .Password = "Swarf"
        .Save
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Not sure about the Protect / Password thing.

Comment: The password seems to be giving me some type of error, any solutions to this?

Comment: I have just slightly modified your code, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is **@Vincent G** answer slightly modified (I have accepted his answer)- just fixed the password error I was getting, I am now using this code and it is working flawlessly!

Leaving this here incase someone else reads this post and wants to know what the end result of everyone's suggestions is, thanks to everyone who contributed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim y As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\FILEPATH\Databases\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf")

    With y
        Sheets("MyTest2").Unprotect "Swarf"

        .Sheets("Mytest2").Range("F2:O2") = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("K1:K10"))

        Password = "Swarf"
        .Save
        .Close False

    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```