# .Net Excel Interop Multiple Columns Delete with range very slow

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop, excel-addins

I am using below code to delete multiple columns with range by using Excel Interop library. It is taking much time to delete the entire columns. Is there any other alternate ways to delete the multiple columns very quickly.

```
Excel.Application _excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Excel.Workbook sourceWorkbook = _excel.ActiveWorkbook;
_excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
_wb = _excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
_wb.Activate();
_wb.Windows[1].Visible = true;
_wb.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
_wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
for (int i = 1; i <= sourceWorkbook.Sheets.Count; i++)
{
   sourceWorkbook.Sheets[i].Activate();
   sourceWorkbook.Sheets[i].Copy(Type.Missing, _wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count]);
   _wb.Activate();
   _wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count].Activate();
   if (_wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count].ProtectContents)
   {
      _wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count].Unprotect(AppConstants.Password);
   }
   _wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count].Columns["IP:XFD"].EntireColumn.Delete(); <-- Here the delete process is taking time
   if (!_wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count].ProtectContents)
   {
     _wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count].Protect(AppConstants.Password);
   }
}
```

Comment: If you haven't already, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673341/net-excel-interop-deleting-a-column-is-very-slow ... I seem to recall the advice re turning off updating may be valuable, especially if you're doing full columns on big data.

Comment: The solution here may be helpful, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391786/effect-of-screen-updating

Comment: @DentonThomas, I have switched off screenupdating as false already. Still the delete process is taking time. I have updated my question as well.

Comment: Try disabling calculation, also? Property/flag is in the second post. As an alternative, if there is any chance IO is your final column... maybe create a new sheet instead and copy A:IO (smaller data set) across, then delete the whole excess sheet. I haven't tried/compared these operations before - it depends on the size of your data set.

Comment: What does _slow_ mean? 5 days? 5 hours? 5 minutes?

Comment: @user246821, I have 53 sheets in the workbook. For deleting the columns in a single worksheet, it is taking 40 to 50 seconds.

Comment: For [Interop.Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia), that may be fast. Although, if one doesn't properly close/dispose of the _Excel_ objects, one may see performance issues on subsequent executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since you specifically want to know how to do this *fast*, I think you have three options:

1. optimise your existing code. Some possibilities:

- Simplify the delete call:

```
_wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count].Columns["IP:XFD"].EntireColumn.Delete();
```

Since your Columns[] argument is *already* full-height columns ... I'm thinking the additional .EntireColumn dereference is superfluous. For the size of your data, that's definitely going to incur some overhead. I *think* this should function identically:

```
_wb.Sheets[_wb.Sheets.Count].Columns["IP:XFD"].Delete();
```

- @user246821 is totally right - free your memory, especially true if this is a function that you're going to run on multiple files and/or multiple times without restarting the addin.
- consider that every call to _wb.Sheets and _wb.Sheets.Count is inside the loop ... and these are not necessarily 'free'. Store the values in temporary variables if possible, then call those temps instead of dereferencing _wb and its components. Someone who has used Interop more than me will have to make further comment on how to store these and/or whether it is worthwhile.
- try *not* copying the workbook in sheete-sized bits inside your loop. Copying via the filesystem will clearly be faster. Can you start with a manually created copy of the complete file? Or could you do a single, complete workbook or file copy operation outside the loop? These would remove flipping back and forth amongst active objects, and may be you can avoid carrying two workbooks around in memory. As a bonus, if you copy the complete file ... maybe you can come up with a way to do the protect/unprotect in bulk?

2. Explore preparing or managing your data using PowerQuery. That *may* be faster and repeatable. That may not integrate with whatever else you are doing, however, and it's not horribly portable ... but it is a valid option.
3. Consider another library, language and/or converting formats. I think a best-case scenario for speed would be if your data is all plain text without formatting already, making your process:

- split out your XLS file to separate CSV files
- Truncate rows. I think you have some 260 columns to keep (hundreds of rows? thousands?) and 53 files ... , and you know C#, so I'm going to guess you could do this faster in C/C++.
- if you actually need it, recombine your CSV files into a single XLS file

Those are the main pathways that come to mind. Unless you are desperate and considering hardware upgrades!